# What do you call a 'sublist', if there may be duplicates and missing values?

Tags: arrays, list, math, set

Suppose you have a list `L`. You consider this to be a 'sublist' of any list `L'` as long as each element of `L` appears in `L'`, in the same order in which they appear in `L`.

Example: a list `[7, 4, 4, 9]` is a 'sublist' of any list `[_, 7, _, 4, _, 4, _, 9, _]`, where each `_` may be zero or more values. It is not a sublist of `[8, 4, 4, 9]`, `[4, 4, 9]`, `[7, 4, 9]`, `[7, 4, 4, 4]`, etc.

If there wouldn't be duplicates, you could say `L` would be an ordered subset of ordered set `L'` (that's probably not strictly correct, but most would know what you meant).

Is there a specific word or term for the 'sublist' relationship that is described here?

Comment: I guess what you are trying to descibe here is a "subsequence".

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subsequence

Comment: Thank you, that makes complete sense!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess what you are trying to descibe here is a "subsequence".

```
In mathematics, a subsequence is a sequence
that can be derived from another sequence 
by deleting some or no elements 
without changing the order of the remaining elements.
```

You can refer to the Wikipedia link below.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subsequence